# Why does SpeechRecognition with the Bing service only recognize the first sentence?

Tags: python, speech-recognition, azure-cognitive-services

I tried [SpeechRecognition package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/SpeechRecognition/) with the Bing ASR service to transcribe [the audio of this clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e7D-xW1VT9Y) with the script

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

"""Recognize speech using Microsoft Bing Voice Recognition."""

import speech_recognition as sr

from os import path
AUDIO_FILE = path.join(path.dirname(path.realpath(__file__)), "input.wav")

# use the audio file as the audio source
r = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.AudioFile(AUDIO_FILE) as source:
    audio = r.record(source)  # read the entire audio file


# Microsoft Bing Voice Recognition API uses keys which are
# 32-character lowercase hexadecimal strings
BING_KEY = "FOOBAR - insert your key here"
try:
    print("Microsoft Bing Voice Recognition thinks you said:\n\n" +
          r.recognize_bing(audio, key=BING_KEY, language="de-DE"))
except sr.UnknownValueError:
    print("Microsoft Bing Voice Recognition could not understand audio")
except sr.RequestError as e:
    print(("Could not request results from Microsoft Bing Voice Recognition "
           "service; {0}").format(e))
```

It outputs:

```
Microsoft Bing Voice Recognition thinks you said:

Reaser Was ist haben sie Lust mit dem Kino zu kommen war schon dass ich könnte den Film gar nicht folgen
```

Obviously, it is working, but it does not transcribe the complete file. Why? How can I make it transcribe the complete file?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the SpeechRecognition package uses the REST interface instead of the WebSocket interface. The REST interface is limited to 15 seconds of audio.

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/azure/cognitive-services/speech/home